# how to get button click event in angular (click event not fire)?

Tags: angularjs, angularjs-directive, onclick, angularjs-scope

Can you please tell me how to get click event of button? Actually button click event does not fire.
Here is plunker
http://plnkr.co/edit/cqmwJc5dpoDWvai4xeNX?p=preview

```
var loginCntrl=function($scope){
  $scope.testClick =function(){
    alert('sss');
  }

}
```

Answer (score 1):

You are making a simple mistake by not including **ng-controller**. Change it as follows. It will work.

```
<div ng-app="firstApp" ng-controller="loginCntrl">

<ui-view name="test"></ui-view>
```